# Creating mongoDB service on rhel6

Tags: linux, mongodb, unix, service, redhat

I have mongoDB cluster and I start all the process manually. 
How can I set them as services in RHEL 6?
The servers are in internal network so I installed the mongoDB from tarballs.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have a sysadmin? Forgive me, but you seem to lack *basic* knowledge of how things work in Linux (or are named, for that matter). The use of RHEL seems to indicate that we are talking of a production environment. In case you don't have a sysadmin, I ***strongly*** suggest getting a [RHCSA](https://www.redhat.com/de/services/certification/rhcsa) and at least [M102](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M102/about)

Comment: Hi, I'm getting M102 now and I'm pretty noob at linux, I just need to get that to work. I'm not the sysadmin and I don't got one right now

Comment: "I just need to get that to work." It doesn't really help you if you do not understand the implications and basic system administration. How will you log? Where to? What will you do with old logs? How? How will you monitor? Do you need a custom run level or will the defaults do fine? How do you make sure that mails to root will be sent to your account? There is *a lot* more to running a MongoDB instance properly than just getting it to start on boot. You are putting the cart in front of the horse.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I'm new in this work (not exactly work but NVM) and the rest of the team will handle all the other things because me being a noob at monogo is known fact ;) I'm just looking for a way to autostart all the needed deamons in the correct order and with the correct argument. I'm thinking about creating a local yum repo with all the needed files and let yum and mongo's scripts do the work. What you think ?

Comment: I think you should figure this out yourself using the  `man man`, `vimtutor` and `apropos` commands. In your case, it will help  *a lot* more then telling you what you want. Learn how to fish instead of asking for one ;)

Comment: Thanks I will check it out !